# Show link in case comment inserted from apex

Tags: apex, trigger, case, standard-objects, case-comment

I have a formula field which returns hyperlink on the `Case` object. When some conditions are met, I insert a `CaseComment` with the formula field value in the body of the comment.

When I reference the formula field directly in case comment body it is showing like below:

```
 caseComment.body = 'This is '+case.formulafieldHyperlink+' code'.
```

Output:

> This is `<a href="urllink" target="_blank"></a>` code

I know `CommentBody` is text, not rich text to show links. Is there any way to show a hyperlink in the body of a `CaseComment`?

Comment: You want to show an actual hyperlink inside a text field? Like clickable hyperlink?

Comment: Yes it should be clickable

Comment: I note that URLs in CaseComments are "adjusted" by SFDC to be wrapped in double quotes `"xxx.foo.com"`

Comment: @cropredy FYI - when I reference the formula field which returns hyperlink in CommentBody, it is rendering the HTML format of anchor tag but not wrapping within quotes as you said

Comment: right, i was observing that while domain names in Case.Description are rendered by the browser as clickable, same domain name in CaseComment is surrounded by `"` and browser won;t render it as clickable

Comment: @cropredy Yes we can have a clickable link in case description but not in case comment body. But our client wants this desperately as it is simple need.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I've never tried this exact use case, but you might try writing it out with an:

```
<apex:outputLink ...> link text </apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: @kavin - FYI - Am trying to insert it from apex trigger.

Comment: am wondering how this could not be possible in case comment as it is a simple user need

Comment: Is there any idea exchange exist to vote for this functionality?